# Using R QDAP: can't allocate memory

Tags: r, dplyr, sparse-matrix, text-mining, qdap

I've tried to use various function in QDAP, such as word_cor, word_associate, ect..., but I continually get back an error that says "can't allocate vector memory of 1.5gb" (something along these lines).

However, I don't need the function to return all of the results of a word_cor (and the like), even at a .7 correlation.  I just want the top 50 or so.

Can/should I use the top_n function in dpylr, or is there another way to dramatically cut down the returns?  I've looked into sparse matrices, but I don't think that's what I need.

Comment: What are you trying to do or understand?

Comment: I'm trying to run a series of tests for descriptive statistics on a large volume of text; the text is organized observation-by-row, and has other data like group, time, etc... Every time I try to run a test I get that error.

Comment: I would suggest qdap is not the right tool for this.  I'd make a document-term-matrix, determine the top n terms you want (using column sums after excluding stopwords) and do your distance measure on this.